# Puppet Agent certificate issue

Tags: centos, certificates, puppet

When I am trying to connect to master server from client; this is what I am getting:

```
puppet agent -t
Error: Could not request certificate: Error 400 on SERVER: The environment must be purely alphanumeric, not 'puppet-ca'
Exiting; failed to retrieve certificate and waitforcert is disabled

/var/log/messages

May 20 08:27:20 app-prd-test xinetd[1989]: START: nrpep pid=32449 from=66.192.29.89
May 20 08:27:20 app-prd-test xinetd[1989]: EXIT: nrpep status=0 pid=32449 duration=0(sec)
May 20 08:28:02 app-prd-test xinetd[1989]: START: nrpep pid=32453 from=66.192.29.89
May 20 08:28:02 app-prd-test xinetd[1989]: EXIT: nrpep status=0 pid=32453 duration=0(sec)
May 20 08:28:26 app-prd-test puppet-agent[32130]: Could not request certificate: Error 400 on SERVER: The environment must be purely alphanumeric, not 'puppet-ca'

root@am-prd-02:/var/lib/puppet/ssl# cat /etc/puppet/puppet.conf | grep -v "#"
[main]
    logdir = /var/log/puppet

    rundir = /var/run/puppet

    ssldir = $vardir/ssl
    server=puppet
    certname=puppet
    dns_alt_names = puppet,puppet.dul.veraction.net

[agent]
    classfile = $vardir/classes.txt

    localconfig = $vardir/localconfig
root@am-prd-02:/var/lib/puppet/ssl#
```

Comment: This is a server side error, so it's a server side configuration issue. How are you can configuring puppet environments? Are you using an ENC like foreman or the puppet enterprise dashboard?

Comment: I just followed below doc:
https://www.digitalocean.com/community/tutorials/how-to-install-puppet-to-manage-your-server-infrastructure

Note: I haven't configured apache for dashboard its a simple puppet Master/Agent configuration on centos 6.7